# How to return rows of table Y based on results of a query on table X?

Tags: mysql

I'm using a mysql database with multiple tables. Let's say I want to retrieve all rows in table X that have `column1` value "C" using the following command:

```
select * from X where column1="C";
```

This returns a list of rows, and in some different column2 of these rows there are a bunch of different values. Call the set of all these values S. How can I retrieve all rows of some different table Y such that only rows with column3 values in S are returned, for some column3 in Y?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with an `IN` expression:

```
SELECT *
FROM Y
WHERE column3 IN (SELECT column2 FROM X WHERE column1='C')
```

or a `JOIN`:

```
SELECT Y.*
FROM Y
JOIN X ON X.column2 = Y.column3 AND X.column1 = 'C'
```